# When I am fatching TileWMS layer information getting this error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEachFeatureAtPixel'

Tags: node.js, openlayers

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEachFeatureAtPixel'

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEachFeatureAtPixel')
    at Map.<anonymous> (main.js:54:18)
    at Map.dispatchEvent (Target.js:114:11)
    at Map.handleMapBrowserEvent (Map.js:1137:14)
    at MapBrowserEventHandler.dispatchEvent (Target.js:114:11)
    at MapBrowserEventHandler.emulateClick_ (MapBrowserEventHandler.js:134:10)
    at MapBrowserEventHandler.handlePointerUp_ (MapBrowserEventHandler.js:227:12)
```

I am using Openalyers 7.1 with Node.js

Comment: Well, that object you are calling `forEachFeatureAtPixel` is `undefined`. Hard to say anything else without seeing a single line of code ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.